# EclipseLink JPA with subselect in the first part of the FROM clause

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have several Oracle SQL querys like this:

```
SELECT USUARIO 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CREATED_BY USUARIO FROM COMPROBANTE_PPTAL);
```

Now, i need the same query in JPA(Eclipselink jpql) format

I have tried this with no luck:

```
SELECT s  FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT c.createdBy AS USUARIO FROM ComprobantePptal c ) s
```

If i execute this in the eclipselink context, i will get this error:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT c.createdBy AS USUARIO FROM ComprobantePptal c) s' cannot be the first declaration of the FROM clause
```

So it means that i can't use subselect in the first part of the from clause.

If i try:

```
SELECT s,c  FROM ComprobantePptal c, (SELECT DISTINCT c.createdBy AS USUARIO FROM ComprobantePptal c ) s
```

Now the query works, but the result are overloaded with 'trash' data that i'm getting with the first part of the from clause.

Is there any way to execute just query in Eclipselink/jpql ?. If the answer is no, please show me workarounds for this that i can use. I have no ideas and i have over 1000 querys like that and using native querys is not an option because i need the project to be database independent.

Comment: You cant use subqueries in the FROM clause of JPQL. End of. Your "workaround" is to use a native query, or rewrite your query so that the from clause uses entities , relations, and/or IN expressions *only*

Comment: @BillyFrost This isn't true at all. Check the eclipselink's JPA documentation.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause
Also, i have already posted an example of working query with subqueries in the FROM clause. The question here is not how to get work subqueries in the from clause, how to get work subqueries in the first part of the subqueries is.

Comment: I comment based on the JPA SPEC, which is where JPQL is defined, go look it up. Go beyond that and your portability has disappeared ... hence your problem

Comment: @BillyFrost In the question i have already defined that i'm working with eclipselink's JPA, not just plain JPQL. And i just need the portability because the final project will be running against several databases  including Oracle, SqlServer and Postgres.